# Read all Parquet files saved in a folder via Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a folder containing Parquet files. Something like this:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4)).toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.write.parquet("/tmp/test/df/1.parquet")

scala> val df = sc.parallelize(List(5,6,7,8)).toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.write.parquet("/tmp/test/df/2.parquet")
```

After saving dataframes when I go to read all parquet files in `df` folder, it gives me error.

```
scala> val read = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/test/df")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:189)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:425)
  ... 48 elided
```

I know I can read Parquet files by giving full path, but it would be better if there is a way to read all parquet files in a folder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Spark doesn't write/read parquet the way you think it does.

It uses the Hadoop library to write/read *partitioned* parquet file.

Thus your first parquet file is under  the path `/tmp/test/df/1.parquet/` where `1.parquet` is a directory. This means that when reading from parquet you would need to provide the path to your parquet directory or path if it's one file.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/test/df/1.parquet/")
```

I advice you to read the official documentation for more details. [cf. [SQL Programming Guide - Parquet Files](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files)]

**EDIT:**

You must be looking for something like this :

```
scala> sqlContext.range(1,100).write.save("/tmp/test/df/1.parquet")

scala> sqlContext.range(100,500).write.save("/tmp/test/df/2.parquet")

scala> val df = sqlContext.read.load("/tmp/test/df/*")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint]

scala> df.show(3)
// +---+
// | id|
// +---+
// |400|
// |401|
// |402|
// +---+
// only showing top 3 rows

scala> df.count
// res3: Long = 499
```

You can also use wildcards in your file paths URI.

And you can provide multiple files paths as followed :

```
scala> val df2 = sqlContext.read.load("/tmp/test/df/1.parquet","/tmp/test/df/2.parquet")
// df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint]

scala> df2.count
// res5: Long = 499
```

Comment: I know that `1.parquet` will be a directory. Actually I want to read all parquet directories in a folder via Spark.

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear in your question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @eliasah. `val df = sqlContext.read.load("/tmp/test/df/*")` worked for me.

Comment: I am writing a Java code for prequet file in Spark version 2.1.1






Code:

`Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("adl://xxxxxxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/test/data.json");
df.write().mode("overwrite").parquet("data.parquet"); 
Dataset<Row> newDataDF = spark.read().parquet("data.parquet/") ; `








It is showing same error 

`"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;"`



can you please assist me ?

Comment: @umarfaraz you should post a question like everyone else. If I have some time to look at it, I will. I'm currently busy.

Comment: I have the same error so i thought of posting it here, And sure take your time @eliasah

Answer (score 1):

The file you wrote on `/tmp/test/df/1.parquet` and `/tmp/test/df/2.parquet` are not a output file they are output Directory.
so, you can read the parquet is

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/test/df/1.parquet/")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write data into folder not as separate Spark "files" (in fact folders) `1.parquet`, `2.parquet` etc.
If don't set file name but only path, Spark will put files into the folder as real files (not folders), and automatically name that files.

```
df1.write.partitionBy("countryCode").format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/data1/")
df2.write.partitionBy("countryCode").format("parquet").mode("append").save("/tmp/data1/")
df3.write.partitionBy("countryCode").format("parquet").mode("append").save("/tmp/data1/")
```

Further we can read data from all files in data folder:

```
val df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("/tmp/data1/")
```